# Long exposure with interval and noise reduction

Tags: long-exposure, noise-reduction, intervalometer

I'm interested about long exposure (4+ minutes) using a camera that does not allow to disable noise reduction and only allows 2 minute long exposure at most.

Would I be better off taking a few 2-min long exposures and average them out, vs many shorter exposures?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuous Bursts of Many Short Exposures vs. A Few Long Exposures for Astrophotography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41848/continuous-bursts-of-many-short-exposures-vs-a-few-long-exposures-for-astrophot)

Comment: Related: [For night photography with lots of unexposed areas, should I go with high ISO and low exposure, or low ISO and high exposure?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43205/15871)

Comment: Also; [Can I get longer than 15 second exposure with my canon SX 50?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/35272/15871) and [Why does the Canon SX60 HS restrict ISO to 100 with exposure times longer than 1.3 seconds?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/98565/15871) and [How can I simulate a long exposure photo using a set of shorter exposure photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8092/15871)